# When does System.abortJob() take effect with regards to a transaction?

Tags: apex, asyncapexjob, transaction

If I call [`System.abortJob()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_system.htm) in a transaction, when is the job actually aborted?

Does it happen immediately, or only once the transaction is committed?

I suspect the latter, as you don't want to have to restart the job if something else causes the transaction to roll back. This came up in answering another [question](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=906F0000000kGdV), but I couldn't find a reference confirming the behavior.

Comment: That's going to be hard to test. Well, looks like I'm losing my weekend.

Comment: I raised this question as it seemed like one of those things that would be interesting to know. I'm travelling for the MVP summit in Chicago shortly and didn't want to forget about it once I departed. If we could make a long running async job then there should be enough time to abort or about and rollback before it completes. Still, one of those things where timing is everything.

Comment: oh. I'll see you there.